# Do Recurrent Convolutional Layers share parameters?

Tags: neural-networks, conv-neural-network, recurrent-neural-network

I'm reading the paper [Recurrent Convolutional Neural Networks for Object Recognition](https://www.cv-foundation.org/openaccess/content_cvpr_2015/papers/Liang_Recurrent_Convolutional_Neural_2015_CVPR_paper.pdf).

I don't understand the idea of weight sharing explained in the article. I am confused between the two following explanations :

*(I've omitted the bias in equations and the images are taken from the article above, where I drew the red abominations)*

**From the left image :** There are two sets of weights. The feed-forward ones ($W_f$) and the one in the hidden recurrent unit ($W_r$) where :

$t_0 = W_f*x$

$t_n = W_f*x + W_r*t_{n-1}$

**From the right image :** The feed-forward weights stay the same but every time there is a new "time step", there are new weights.

$t_0 = W_f*x$

$t_n = W_f*x + W_{rn}*t_{n-1}$

I have a feeling the answer is the left image, but I don't understand how doing this would be useful (so, I guess that's a part two of my original question).

[image]
[image]